# tr, td widths in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, email-client

All solutions I have scoured on SO are not helping me resolve my issue.  I cannot get width on my tr and td's to work in the Outlook Email Client.  Here is a sample:

```
    <table width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 600px; margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; height: 150px; background-color: #ffffff; table-layout: fixed; padding: 20px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
    <!--Header Row-->
    <tr width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
      <td width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><a href="http://example.org" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; text-decoration: none;"> <img src="http://example.img-us3.com/BarberJ/header-image-560.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="header-image.png" title="header-image.png" style="box-sizing: border-box;"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--End Header Row--><!--Hero Image Row-->
    <tr style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
      <td style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><img src="http://example.img-us3.com/BarberJ/hero-image-560.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="hero-image.png" title="hero-image.png" style="box-sizing: border-box;"></td>
    </tr>
    <!--End Hero Image--><!--Main Heading/CTA-->
    <tr width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
      <td width="75%" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 75%; display: inline-block; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
        <h1 style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 26px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: 800; color: #425563; margin-top: 4px;">Knitting New Knockers</h1>
        <p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 4px; font-weight: 100; color: #425563;">How a knitting Group is putting the 'ta-da' back in ta-tas.</p>
      </td>
      <td width="25%" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 0; width: 25%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="box-sizing: border-box;">
              <td bgcolor="#9F1C3B" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; border-radius: 30px; color: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" align="center"><a target="_blank" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: white;">Discover How</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried adding fixed widths to all td's and tr's.  I have tried removing any percentages.  Nothing is working in Outlook...where is my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the third `<tr>` row, you You added a second `<td>` with a width of 25%.

The way to get cleaner output is to divide the table into two tables, one for the first two rows of images and one for the rest of the table with two rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <table width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 600px; margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; height: 150px; background-color: #ffffff; table-layout: fixed; padding: 20px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
    <!--Header Row-->
    <tr width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
      <td width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><a href="http://example.org" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; text-decoration: none;"> <img src="http://example.img-us3.com/BarberJ/header-image-560.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="header-image.png" title="header-image.png" style="box-sizing: border-box;"></a></td>
   </tr>
   <!--End Header Row--><!--Hero Image Row-->
   <tr style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
     <td style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><img src="http://example.img-us3.com/BarberJ/hero-image-560.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="hero-image.png" title="hero-image.png" style="box-sizing: border-box;"></td>
   </tr>
  <!--End Hero Image--><!--Main Heading/CTA-->
</table>
<table width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 600px; margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; height: 150px; background-color: #ffffff; table-layout: fixed; padding: 20px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
<tr width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
  <td width="75%" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 75%; display: inline-block; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
    <h1 style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 26px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: 800; color: #425563; margin-top: 4px;">Knitting New Knockers</h1>
    <p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 4px; font-weight: 100; color: #425563;">How a knitting Group is putting the 'ta-da' back in ta-tas.</p>
  </td>
  <td width="25%" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 0; width: 25%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
      <tbody>
        <tr style="box-sizing: border-box;">
          <td bgcolor="#9F1C3B" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; border-radius: 30px; color: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" align="center"><a target="_blank" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: white;">Discover How</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how your table will look in Outlook 2016 after the fix:

Good luck.
[image: Your table cell in Outlook 2016 with border=1]

Answer (score 0):

You were missing td's so to speak. You bigger two images are on single td's and the very bottom row was on two td's. Thats the reason your tables were not aligning.Also try not to use box-sizing, older browsers dont read it and its just code taking up file size. All email devs know how a few kilobytes are important in emails.

```html
<table width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 600px; margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; height: 150px; background-color: #ffffff; table-layout: fixed; padding: 20px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
  <tr style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
    <td style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><table width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 600px; margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; height: 150px; background-color: #ffffff; table-layout: fixed; padding: 20px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
        <!--Header Row-->
        <tr width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
          <td width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><a href="http://example.org" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; text-decoration: none;"> <img src="http://example.img-us3.com/BarberJ/header-image-560.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="header-image.png" title="header-image.png" style="box-sizing: border-box;"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <!--End Header Row-->
        <!--Hero Image Row-->
        <tr style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
          <td style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><img src="http://example.img-us3.com/BarberJ/hero-image-560.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="hero-image.png" title="hero-image.png" style="box-sizing: border-box;"></td>
        </tr>
        <!--End Hero Image-->
        <!--Main Heading/CTA-->
      </tbody>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 600px; margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; height: 150px; background-color: #ffffff; table-layout: fixed; padding: 20px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
  <tbody width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
    <!--Header Row-->
    <!--End Header Row-->
    <!--Hero Image Row-->
    <!--End Hero Image-->
    <!--Main Heading/CTA-->
    <tr width="600" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;">
      <td width="75%" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 75%; display: inline-block; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><h1 style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 26px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: 800; color: #425563; margin-top: 4px;">Knitting New Knockers</h1>
        <p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 4px; font-weight: 100; color: #425563;">How a knitting Group is putting the 'ta-da' back in ta-tas.</p></td>
      <td width="25%" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 0; width: 25%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
        <tbody>
          <tr style="box-sizing: border-box;">
            <td bgcolor="#9F1C3B" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; border-radius: 30px; color: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;" align="center"><a target="_blank" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: white;">Discover How</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this was the answer you were after.